# How to find the tag of a generic control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I'm creating a function that allows you to search for a control by the tag. The only parameter is the name of the tag. It returns a list of all the type `T` controls with the tag. This is what I have:

```
public static List<T> FindWithTag<T>(string tag)
{
    List<T> types = new List<T>();

    foreach (T type in fm.Controls.OfType<T>())
        if (type.Tag == tag)
            types.Add(type);
    return types;
}
```

Problem is, since `T` is a generic variable, it doesn't have a tag property. I can understand why, because could be an `int` or a `string`. How can I tell the compiler that `T` is only for controls, and would therefore have a tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The magic search term is a "[generic constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the type which should your T type be inherited from.

```
public static T[] FindWithTag<T>(string tag) where T : Control
{
    List<T> types = new List<T>();

    foreach (T type in fm.Controls.OfType<T>())
        if (type.Tag == tag)
            types.Add(type);
    return types;
}
```

By the way, calling a foreach local variable `type` confused me because actually you are enumerating through controls. So, it should be

```
 foreach (T control in fm.Controls.OfType<T>())
```

It also applies to `List<T> types` which is, by fact, a list of *Control*. Sometimes, incorrect name of a single variable can make code much less readable :)

Comment: With that type restriction the whole method body can become `return fm.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(type => type.Tag == tag).ToArray();`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Haha, yeah, as I was typing it I felt that there could be some confusion with the variable name. But this works perfect, thanks for the help! :)